# Pandas Group By and Sorting by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have some initial data that looks like this:

```
code          type          value
1111          Golf     Acceptable
1111          Golf    Undesirable
1111    Basketball     Acceptable
1111    Basketball    Undesirable
1111    Basketball    Undesirable
```

and I'm trying to group it on the `code` and `type` columns to get the row with the most occurrences. In the case of a tie, I want to select the row with the value `Undesirable`. So the example above would become this:

```
code          type          value
1111          Golf    Undesirable
1111    Basketball    Undesirable
```

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['code', 'type', 'value']).size().reset_index(name='count'))

df = df.sort_values(['type', 'count'])

df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['code', 'type']).last().reset_index())
```

I've done some testing of this and it *seems* to do what I want, but I don't really like trusting the `.last()` call, and hoping in the case of a tie that `Undesirable` was sorted last. Is there a better way to group this to ensure I always get the higher count, or in the cases of a tie select the `Undesirable` value?

Performance isn't too much of an issue as I'm only working with around 50k rows or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Case 1

If the `value` column only contains two values i.e. `['Acceptable', 'Undesirable']` then we can rely on the fact that `Acceptable` < `Undesirable` alphabetically. In this case you can use the following simplified solution.

Create an auxiliary column called `count` which contain the count of number of rows per `code`, `type` and `value`. Then sort the dataframe by `count` and `value` and drop the dupes per `code` and `type` keeping the last row.

```
c = ['code', 'type']
df['count'] = df.groupby([*c, 'value'])['value'].transform('count')
df.sort_values(['count', 'value']).drop_duplicates(c, keep='last')
```

##### Case 2

If the `value` column contains other values and you can't rely  on alphabetical ordering use the following solution which is similar to solution proposed in case 1 but this first converts the value column to ordered `Categorical` type before sorting

```
c = ['code', 'type']

df['count'] = df.groupby([*c, 'value'])['value'].transform('count')
df['value'] = pd.Categorical(df['value'], categories=['Acceptable', 'Undesirable'], ordered=True)

df.sort_values(['count', 'value']).drop_duplicates(c, keep='last')
```

##### Result

```
   code        type        value  count
1  1111        Golf  Undesirable      1
4  1111  Basketball  Undesirable      2
```

Comment: In my case, the values are always `Acceptable` or `Undesirable` so Case 1 works. Line 2 of that answer is adding a `count` column onto every row, rather than reducing them to 1 row per occurrence with a count like my code was correct? So theoretically, what I really need is just the line 3 to drop the duplicates, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on the following ideas:

1. Grouping the data by `code` and `type`.
2. If a group has more than one row (`len(x) > 1`) and its rows have the same count (`x['count'] == x['count'].min()).all()`), return the row with `Undesirable`.
3. Otherwise, return the row where the count is maximum (`x.iloc[[x['count'].argmax()]]`).

```
(df.groupby(['code', 'type', 'value'])['value'].size()
 .reset_index(name='count').groupby(['code', 'type'])
 .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['value'] == 'Undesirable'] if 
        ((len(x) > 1) and (x['count'] == x['count'].min()).all()) else
        x.iloc[[x['count'].argmax()]])
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .drop('count', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   code        type        value
0  1111  Basketball  Undesirable
1  1111        Golf  Undesirable
```